# How to add a RaisedButton inside the Card with the height same as the card?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I want to add a button in the right side of the card,by default the button's color should be green and while tapping on it, there should be a popup box opened and the color of the button would turn to red.

```
1-The button's color should be green while the listView willed be plotted. 
2-Then when I am tapping on the button, a dialog box should be opened with a input textField.
3-After I am inserting any text and pressing the submit button of the popup box, the entered text will be printed on the console.
4-Then the color of the button would turn to red from green.
```

As I am new to flutter, please help me to get this.
Here is my Code:

```
body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: patients.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 120,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 5.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 3,
                          child: Container(
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(patients[index].imgPath),
                              radius: 50.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 5,
                          child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(patients[index].name, style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 23.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black87
                                ),),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                Text(patients[index].completedSession.toString() +'/'+ patients[index].totalSession.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black54
                                ),),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Container(
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` for your `Row`:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pushed = useState(false);
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 3,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5.0,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/RowanAtkinsonMar07.jpg',
                ),
                radius: 50.0,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Mister B.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 23.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black87),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '0/42',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black54),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                          pushed.value ? 'Button unpushed' : 'Button pushed'),
                    ),
                  );
                  pushed.value = !pushed.value;
                },
                color: pushed.value ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I also simplified your widget tree. You don't need to use `Container`s everywhere.